# C++ Winform How to parse string array to int array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, winforms, int

In the main objective, I need to change the input from `("5,23,12,23...")` to `("5 23 12 ... ")` by remove the comma `,`.

I have already removed this comma but the next object is finding min and max from this input number. I don't know how to parse `array<string>` to `array<int>` to do the next objective.

I can't do this `number[word]=Convert::ToInt32(words[word]);` so please someone tell me the way how to solve this.

```
String^ strInput="";
String^ strResult="";
String^ strRemove=",";

array<Char>^Remove=strRemove->ToCharArray();
array<String^>^words;
array<Int32^>^number;
int test;
//get text from input ui
strInput=txtInput->Text;
words=strInput->Split(Remove);

for(int word=0;word<words->Length;word++)
{
    /*number[word]=Convert::ToInt32(words[word]);*/
    test=Int32::Parse(words[word]);
    txtResult->Text+=words[word]+" ";
}
```

Comment: This is not C++. Probably C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

should be solved by adding:

```
number = gcnew array<Int32^>(words->Length);
```

before your **for Loop**

then your currently commented line should work.